# Remote access with xfce4 installed on Chromebook ASUS CN60

Tags: ssh, xfce, asus, chromebook, chroot

I have ASUS chromebox CN60 with installed XFCE4.12 (Xubuntu). XFCE is automatically starting on chromebox startup with specific website in web browser. Everything is working good, but I have problem with remote access from server with Xubuntu.

I have installed `ssh`, `ssh-agent`, `xrdp`, `vnc server` and could't connect.
Ping from server is OK. Network is working. I've installed `firewall` and enable/disable it.

I try to use `putty`, `tightvnc`, `windows rdp`.

Also I can't use `sudo reboot` in Xubuntu terminal. Answer is :

```
Running in chroot, ignoring request
```

I have tried to change user for root, but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?